# Tool for processing Chinese text

Tags: pinyin, traditional-vs-simplified, software

[DimSum](http://mandarintools.com/dimsum.html) is (was) a Java tool I found useful for Chinese on MacOS, but it is twelve years old and the website says it should solve some “problems on Snow Leopard” (Snow Leopard is 2009, version 10.6; current is 12.6, about to become 13.0)  DimSum will not run on 12.x (and in one try, it actually crashed the O.S.)

It could convert to pinyin, convert Traditional to Simplified (and vice versa), insert word breaks, and provide definitions for characters or for words.  Had other functions that I never used.

Suggestion for an alternative?

Comment: Did you try the google language input keyboard?

Comment: The related links at the bottom of the page points to some other applications.... for example, this one: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ihanzim/id553311934?ls=1 Free with in-app purchase, worth a try?

Comment: It's worth a try, but it is an iPad app, so it's not a great substitute for DimSum.  I'd have to copy text, paste it into Notes, wait for iCloud to sync, copy and paste into the app.  Also it may do what I was using DimSum for, but the description only mentions definitions (for which I already have Pleco on iPad).

Comment: google language input keyboard is "Available for Google services, Chrome, Android devices, and Windows" it supports typing (which is already built into MacOS) and definitions; none of the other things.  But the two biggest disadvantages are it does not work on any version of MacOS, and it comes from NSA's biggest competitor.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a MAC, try to install a JDK 1.4.

[image]

another solution is:

here are some alternatives, you can try:

[image]

https://en.freedownloadmanager.org/Windows-PC/DimSum-FREE.html

Comment: Those alternatives look good, though with so many features, I am not sure it actually has the ones I need.  Didn't look hard because they are Windows-only, so of no use to me.  (Maybe with Wine, but the last few things I tried with that didn't work.)  But trying with an older JDK is a good idea.

Comment: Yes, just have a try. because Java is cross-platform. you can run .jar file in MAC,WIN,LINUX...